# Angular-ui's tooltip does not display correctly in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

I've been searching for some time for a solution for displaying a tooltip on ng-grid but with no luck. When I use the cellTemplate on ng-grid for customizing the cell to include a tooltip I have experienced various problems - the tooltip is either not showing up or behaving strangely as shown in a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/MFhwgOvSUFKcyJPse5wf.

Have I missed something? Does anyone have a solution for displaying tooltips nicely in ng-grid?

Best regards.

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/317

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I commented, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/317) inside an ng-grid cell.  I fixed this by setting cellClass in the column definition to this:

```
cellClass: 'cellToolTip'
```

And the css:

```
.cellToolTip {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XIumChPPws1TveiSeljI?p=preview) that shows the tooltip.  However, the tooltip is not positioned exactly right. :)

**EDIT**:
Adding this to the `.tooltip` style fixed the positioning problem, but I'm not sure why in Plunker I had to do this.  In my own code, this was not necessary:

```
.tooltip {
  top: 0 !important;
}
```

Here is a [new plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XcZvo7?p=preview) that is working.

Comment: Thanks - however the positioning is important, do you have any suggestion on how to position the tooltip right?

Comment: It will have to do with your template.  I'll take a look.

Comment: Interesting issue with your solution. {name: "Tiancum Has a lot of information in it, so it goes off the side of the chart and creates a horizontal scroll", age: 43},

Comment: Both above plunkers are not working now.Can you fix it ?

Answer (score 37):

You can use

```
tooltip-append-to-body="true"
```

as documented here (scroll down to tooltip):
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Here is the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/nHN2p8qMjT7ZTwpXgJoO?p=preview

Comment: This worked for me and the accepted answer didn't. Using angular 1.2.2, angular-ui 0.4, ng-grid 2.0.7.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed in more recent version and the correct way to do this is this answer.

Comment: Fixed. ng-grid source code was moved. The plunkers aren't working in their own documentation right now for the same reason.