# Unable to style a cell tooltip of ngGrid

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, ng-grid

I am trying to add a tooltip to my cells. Using the title attribute works, but the style is different from the rest of the page (bootstrap styling)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQMmj.png

Changing the title attribute to tooltip doesn't work - it looks like it hides the tooltip under the next cell (changing the coordination of the tooltip to something within the range of the cell, made it partially visible).

(I am new so I cant post images, https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/800 )

Any idea whats wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check this previous SO post ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338804/angular-uis-tooltip-does-not-display-correctly-in-ng-grid