# show tooltip on the click of the cell in ng-grid : Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

in my ng-grid options I have :

```
columnDefs : [
 {
                                    field : 'status',
                                    headerClass : 'tbl-header',
                                    displayName : 'Status',
                                    cellTemplate : '<span tooltip="{{row.entity.note}}" tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip-trigger:"focus">{{row.entity.status}}</span>'
                                },

],
```

But this does not display the tooltip on the click of the column cell. However, if I remove the  `tooltip-trigger:"focus"` then the tooltip appears on the hover.

How can i show the tooltip on the click event of the cell template?

Comment: Have you tried using `tooltip-trigger="click"`?

Comment: Nope was using focus as that was defined

Answer (score 0):

As it explained here :

[Angular-ui's tooltip does not display correctly in ng-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338804/angular-uis-tooltip-does-not-display-correctly-in-ng-grid)

you can use

> tooltip-append-to-body="true"

to append tooltip to body.